# Compatability issue

Tags: android, permissions, android-manifest, publishing

I'm new to publishing apps in android. I just recently published my app. But after I did, the list of compatible devices shows that the only two devices that I ran my app on, during development, are not compatible! This is puzzling. I understand this has to do with my manifest file. Here are the permissions:

```
 <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="9"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />   

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />   
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />   
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />    
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />    


<supports-screens android:resizeable="true"
              android:smallScreens="true" 
              android:normalScreens="true"
              android:largeScreens="true"
              android:xlargeScreens="true"     
              android:anyDensity="true"           
             />
```

Please tell me where I have gone wrong. The two devices in question are Samsung Galaxy Pocket (GT-S5300) and Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 (7.0).

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the GTab2 (GT-P3113) does not have autofocus. Probably the same with the Pocket. The GTab2's camera is *horrible*. Note that ADB doesn't care whether your device has the features your app needs... only the Play store filters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since those two devices lack autofocus replace the line with

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
```

with

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" android:required="false"/>
```

It should solve the problem.

Comment: All right, and when I'm done doing this I just replace the already published apk file with the new one, or do I upload it as a new release?

Comment: I would delete and upload it again.